# How do you raise a CKEditor dialog after another is exited?

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to use CKEditor dialogs to create a wizard experience for the user. The first CKEditor dialog will have a form and after completion and after clicking okay, I want to raise a second CKEditor dialog.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this. It cannot be done as part of the first dialog's onOk or by listening for the first dialog's hide event because both of those happen before the first dialog is done being executed and so trying to raise a second dialog at that point causes CKEditor to blow up.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or does anyone have a recommendation for how to achieve stated functionality?

We are using CKEditor 4.4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of launching multiple dialogs one after the other, try staying within a single dialog (the OK button finishes wizard execution and closes the dialog) and build the steps as part of a large [html content element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.html). The html element will perform the logic of each step and display next/prev buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was trying to avoid that (I cannot qualify why I wanted to). But if that's the way to do it, then so be it.